# Forming ECC key (TLS) in X9.63 format

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, tls

I am studying TLS handshaking by example a program [tlse](https://github.com/eduardsui/tlse/blob/master/tlse.c), which uses libtomcrypt library.
I see that in line 5236 (link above) the program call libtomcrypt procedure `ecc_ansi_x963_export(context->ecc_dhe, out, &out_len)` .
I see that the procedure forms a ECC key in the buffer `out` and add it to client "key_share" extension in the line 5248.
 My question is: what is the format X9.63 ? Does it specifies a format of ECC key - bytes in the big endian order or something else ? (unfortunately, I'm confused in terminology - could you explain it to me)

Comment: It's probably just the encoding of the **public key point**. The public point is usually encoded as a binary array starting with a byte starting with `0x02`, `0x03` or `0x04`. The first two indicate a compressed point (one additional bit is required for calculating the $y$ value from the $x$ value), and `0x04` is to indicate an uncompressed point containing both. The coordinates $x$ and $y$ are encoded in a statically sized big integer value; the size is the same as the key size in bytes. Please include the result in `out` in hexadecimals, as the public key point may be ASN.1 DER encoded too.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: TLS1.3 allows only (the equivalent of) uncompressed, and wraps the result in TLS format not DER (in contrast to e.g. PKIX certs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official X9.63 format is the same as the X9.62 format (which is now withdrawn, but memorialized other places including SEC1) and actually had *three* forms -- uncompressed, compressed, and hybrid -- plus a special case for the identity element, commonly called the 'point at infinity' when affine coordinates are used, as they are for Weierstrass curve form in X9. In practice nobody used hybrid form and nobody wants to use (thus encode) the identity element, so e.g. [rfc5480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480.html#section-2.2) for a PKIX certificate and [rfc5656](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656.html#section-3.1) for SSH2 both reference SEC1.

However, [key_share in TLS1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#section-4.2.8.2) is a little different. It redefines, using the TLS notation, the equivalent of uncompressed form only -- one byte 04, fixed-length big-endian unsigned x and y -- not allowing compressed form. In contrast [ECC in TLS1.0-1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492.html#page-18) defined `ECPoint` used for server public-key *and* optionally for explicit curve parameters (which pretty much nobody ever used and were removed in TLS1.3) and [client public-key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492.html#section-5.7) by reference to X9.62 and allowed uncompressed or optionally compressed subject to the "supported point formats" negotiated in the Hello exchange.